# How to divide sing column by multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, divide

I want to divide single column by multiple columns (Z/A1~A10) and return value on multiple columns.(A1~A10)

Hear is my dataframe.

```
ID  A1  A2  A3  A4  …   A10 Z
1   6   9   3   3   4   3   69
2   8   3   8   3   3   10  85
3   1   2   4   4   7   5   93
4   1   6   6   4   7   5   91
5   6   4   6   8   10  10  79
6   8   10  7   2   7   10  50
7   10  3   4   7   10  2   63
8   4   7   3   7   6   1   91
```

My expected output is below.

```
ID  A1        A2      A3      A4    …        A10    Z
1    11.5    7.7     23.0    23.0    17.3    23.0   69
2    10.6    28.3    10.6    28.3    28.3    8.5    85
3    93.0    46.5    23.3    23.3    13.3    18.6   93
4    91.0    15.2    15.2    22.8    13.0    18.2   91
5    13.2    19.8    13.2    9.9     7.9     7.9    79
6    6.3     5.0     7.1     25.0    7.1     5.0    50
7    6.3     21.0    15.8    9.0     6.3     31.5   63
8    22.8    13.0    30.3    13.0    15.2    91.0   91
```

I already tried by this code.

```
list = [A1, A2, A3, ... A10]
df.loc[:, list] = df['Z'] / df[:, list]
```

However, the result is blank on A1~A10 columns.
How can I make a code for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

cols = ['A' + str(n) for n in range(1,11)]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0,10, (8,10)),
    columns=cols
)

df['Z'] = np.random.randint(0,70, 8)
```

**Compute**

Leverage the fact that pandas dataframes are basically just numpy arrays. Access only the columns you want to apply a function on (that's what the `df.loc[:, 'A10']` was for. See [pandas docs for help on slicing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)).

the `.apply` method needs a function and by default is applied to each column (i.e. a column is the input argument). This means that you're dividing the column Z (`df['Z']`) by the values of every column in df (`df['A1']`, `df['A2']`, etc...)

as I mentioned, pandas data structures are built on top of numpy arrays. So dividing an 8 x 1 shaped array (the `df['Z']` column) by another 8 x 1 array (every other column), will mean you will be dividing each element by the equivalent element (first in Z divided by first in the other column, 2nd to 2nd, 3rd to 3rd, etc...)

```
df.loc[:, 'A10'].apply(lambda col: df['Z'] / col)
```

Answer (score 1):

`df.loc[:, list] = df.loc[:, list].apply(lambda col: df.Z / col)`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply iterate over the columns and divide:

```
for col in df.drop('Z',axis=1).columns:
    df[col] = df['Z'] / df[col]
```